# How to find the Python version in which a given script was made?

Tags: python, compatibility

I was given a Python script to work with and modify as part of a job. At first I run it on a old installation of Anaconda, and a given version of the Spyder IDE (if that matters) and everything worked perfectly.
Then I had the bad idea of updating everything (anaconda navigator, python version, the IDE..) and now It fails to return the expected plots, even after adressing the errors given by the console (most about sintaxis changes).

I tried creating different environments in anaconda with some older python versions but that didn't fixed it so far. Also tried to run it outside of anaconda but that didnt work either.

My question is how can I find the version of python (or anaconda and whatever software is involved in the compatibility) so that I can run it as I did in the begining? or how can I do it whitout trying every single python version?. Also if anyone has a better idea on how to proceed to solve the problem is very welcomed.

Comment: I would check the versions of the software in the backup that you made prior to updating. If you did not backup then that is a lesson to learn from. One possible method is to check which functions have been replaced or updated and find out in which version those changes happened. Most software have a timeline of changes...

Comment: A Python script is just a text file. It's not made *by* any given Python interpreter. If you have no documentation at all for what version of Python it targets, you can probably just use the latest version of Python you can get. (Ignoring Python 2, there's very little in Python itself that hasn't stayed backwards compatible.) (What versions of various 3rd-party modules you might need is another story.)

Comment: Are you using a framework or anything for this? If the framework has a requirements.txt file it might help

Comment: It's unspecific. See [ask]. Anyway, you were given a script. Then why not ask the one who wrote that script?